# Fast reading large table

Tags: c#, multithreading, csv

I have csv file structured as below:

```
1,0,2.2,0,0,0,0,1.2,0
0,1,2,4,0,1,0.2,0.1,0
0,0,2,3,0,0,0,1.2,2.1
0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0.2,0.1
0,0,1,0,2.1,0.1,0,1.2
0,0,2,3,0,1.1,0.1,1.2
0,0.2,0,1.2,2,0,3.2,0
0,0,1.2,0,2.2,0,0,1.1
```

but with 10k columns and 10k rows.
I want to read it in such a way that in the result i get a dictionary
with Key as a index of the row and Value as float array filed with every value in this row.
 For now my code look like this:

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
 var result = lines.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select((line, index) =>
 {
    var values = line?.Split(',').Where(v =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
         .Select(f => f.Replace('.', ','))      
         .Select(float.Parse).ToArray();
    return (index, values);     
  }).ToDictionary(d => d.Item1, d => d.Item2);
```

but it takes up to 30 seconds to finish, so it's quite slow and i want to optimize it to be a bit faster.

Comment: Well you can let it be lazy by taking out the ToList() might use the disk better

Comment: This is not premature optimization, this is actually just optimization

Comment: And on saying that there are many ways you can do this, and unfortunatly stackoverflow is not really the place to ask such questions, try code review

Comment: Line 1: change `ReadAllLines` to `ReadLines`, remove that `.ToList()`. Line 4: remove that Where and instead use the Split overload that takes a `StringSplitOptions`. Line 6: combine the second `Select` with the first one. Line 7: consider changing that tuple to an anonymous object

Comment: It isn't possible for `line` to be null, is it possible for the file to have empty lines? Is it really possible for the file to have missing values (e.g. `,,`)?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Removing `ToList` will make `AsParallel` less useful.

Comment: @NetMage For all we know, the 30s might be 29s reading the file. `AsParallel().AsOrdered()` isn't too useful anyway

Comment: The fact the OP hasn't profiled the application makes me also suspect this is premature optimization. I also suspect most time will be spent in reading from the disk, so `AsParallel` will not help. Consider `StreamReader` instead of `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: What is your expectation for reading that many text values from disk, converting to float and storing them?

Comment: @DourHighArch `ReadLines` uses a `StreamReader` to move through the lines and it's easier to read. See [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/ReadLinesIterator.cs,25)

Comment: The `Dictionary` seems overkill if the key is just the row index - the index is free in a List or Array, so `ToDictionary` seems like pure overhead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto @DourHighArch A quick LINQPad test says I can read the file from disk with `ToList` in 1.4 secs, but rest of processing takes 20 secs.

Comment: Your file is what, 300 Mb ? Read it into memory as a binary and parse there.

Comment: @NetMage And after my comment? I didn't test it, so I'm curious

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp Seems like the `ToDictionary` doesn't have much overhead - time varies more than using `ToList` saves.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have modified the body, but I didn't notice the `ReadAllLines().ToList()` was wasting so much time. Changing to `ReadLines` without the `ToList` and time was halved, so `ReadLines().AsParallel()` is still faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are many small optimizations you can make, what is really killing you is the garbage collector because of all the allocations.

Your code takes 12 seconds to run on my machine. Reading the file uses 2 of those 12 seconds.

By using all the optimizations mentioned in the comments (using `File.ReadLines`, `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, also using `float.Parse(f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead of calling `string.Replace`), we get down to 9 seconds. There's still a lot of allocations done, especially by `File.ReadLines`. Can we do better?

Just activate server GC in the app.config:

```
<runtime>   
  <gcServer enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

With that, the execution time drops to 6 seconds using your code, and 3 seconds using the optimizations mentioned above. At that point, the file I/O are taking more than 60% of the execution time, so it's not really worth optimizing more.

Final version of the code:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);

var separator = new[] {','};

var result = lines.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select((line, index) =>
{
    var values = line?.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(f => float.Parse(f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
    return (index, values);
}).ToDictionary(d => d.Item1, d => d.Item2);
```

Comment: why does gcserver save so much time? I thought it's only useful for multi-processors setups

Comment: gcserver doesn't save any time on my PC (4 cores hyperthreaded, 32GB RAM).

Comment: Might be safer to use `float.TryParse()`?

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the `Split` and `Replace` with hand parsing and using `InvariantInfo` to accept the period as decimal point, and then removing the wasteful `ReadAllLines().ToList()` and letting the `AsParallel()` read from the file while parsing, speeds up on my PC about four times.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath);
var result = lines.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select((line, index) => {
    var values = new List<float>(10000);
    var pos = 0;
    while (pos < line.Length) {
        var commapos = line.IndexOf(',', pos);
        commapos = commapos < 0 ? line.Length : commapos;
        var fs = line.Substring(pos, commapos - pos);
        if (fs != String.Empty) // remove if no value is ever missing
            values.Add(float.Parse(fs, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
        pos = commapos + 1;
    }
    return values;
}).ToList();
```

Also replaced `ToArray` on `values` with a `List` as that is generally faster (`ToList` is preferred over `ToArray`).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Not sure what you mean - the number is parsed with one method call, `float.Parse(fs, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If you meant parse the `line`, not using `Split` to create an array that is thrown away and using a lambda to parse but pulling each comma-separated value out is much faster.

Comment: I suspect that counting the number of `,` in `line` and using that value to preallocate the `List<float>` at the right size could save some time

Comment: @KevinGosse I wondered about that, but it seems the overhead of going through the 36k `line` to count 10,000 commas is more than the growth of line. But no reason I can't just assume (roughly) 10,000 items... but it only saves two percent. Even assuming every line is 10k values and replacing the `List` with a `float[10000]` doesn't save another 1%.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If there was an `IEnumerable` version of `Split`, that would be easy to understand and fast. I may have one already written...

Answer (score -3):

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

       protected void CSVImport(string importFilePath)
        {
            string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(importFilePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("WINDOWS-1250"));
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {


                var parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(row));
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                string[] fields;
                fields = parser.ReadFields();
               //do what you need with data in array
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please do not answer with code dumps, specially when you are introducing libraries

Comment: This code does not capture the index of each row, nor does it create a `float[]` of each line for the value. How does this improve what the OP already has? Which part of their code should be replaced with this?